# JQuery if statement not working as expecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and creating an if statement with JQuery to make my navbar collapse when anything on the body is clicked, but only when the browser width is less than 992px. When the browser is 992px or wider, I want this function to be ignored. My function below is working as expected, except for the fact that "test" gets logged to the console when the body is clicked on all browser widths when it should only do so when it is less than 992px. Is something wrong with my if statement below?

```
if ($(window).width() < 992) {
    $('body').click(function() {
        console.log("test");
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
};
```

I updated my code to have the if statement inside of the function, as seen below. It still functions properly and only logs "test" to the console on the correct browser width, but I'm wondering if this is a bad way to do it as the browser will be checking its width on every click even when I don't want it to. Is that a bad way of doing things? Is it better practice to try to get the first code I posted to work?

```
$('body').click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        console.log("test");
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    };    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second method is the way to go.  The first one will only bind the `click` event if the width is less than 992 when that block of code initially executes.

What if the user resizes the browser after the initial decision to bind/not bind has been made?  That's why you need to check the width on every click.

Answer (score 1):

If you bind your click event handler using [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), you can use the [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event to only have the handler bound when the screen is under your desired width. The [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function does the job. For example:

```
var collapseNavbar = function() {
    console.log("test");//remove when done with testing
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('body').bind('click',collapseNavbar);
    } else {
        $('body').unbind('click',collapseNavbar);
    }
});
```

This way the check for window width is only done while/after resizing, and not on every click.

The bound function can be named as you wish, just make sure it is indeed named so unbinding can work properly. As the documentation says:

> By naming the handler, we can be assured that no other functions are accidentally removed.

I'm not sure if the resize event is raised when the page is loaded, though. You might need to add a little snippet to ensure the behavior is present for a browser window which starts at a width lower than 992px (i.e. if you refreshed the page after resizing, or if you're viewing it on a smartphone). Something like this should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('body').bind('click',collapseNavbar);
    }
});
```